# (VB.NET) System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file

Tags: vb.net, file, exception

I am fetching about 600 000 rows into a DataGridView (through SQL) and splitting them all into files by the date.

I tried several ways to do this, and while I found some ways to make it not crash and do it safely and securely, it's EXTREMELY slow.

The fastest way, however, I found to be simply cutting the date only out of the Date column, e.g. turning 2020/06/01 13:50:43 into 0601, and using that as the file name and then just append text to that file. (As opposed to either creating all the rows in a temp object and writing it all at once etc).

It's fast and everything is good, however after writing about, maybe 30? out of about 150 files, it crashes. It's very random, I tried running it a couple of times. It could crash after a few seconds or after half a minute. Hence, I believe it's caused by it tripping itself when trying to write so many times so fast.

I have tried changing the method to write several times, making sure to use Using blocks, as well as trying file share.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub btnExec_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExec.Click
        Static start_time As DateTime
        Static stop_time As DateTime
        Dim elapsed_time As TimeSpan
        start_time = Now

        If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then columnNumber = CInt(TextBox1.Text) - 1
        Dim dgw = Form1.DataGridView1
        Dim curcell As String = ""
        Dim ToWrite As String = ""
        Dim Written As Integer = 0
        Try

            ProgressBar1.Maximum = dgw.Rows.Count
            For i = 0 To dgw.Rows.Count - 1
                'For each row
                If IsDBNull(dgw.Rows(i).Cells(columnNumber).Value.ToString()) Then
                    curcell = "" 'if null replace with a blank value
                Else
                    curcell = CStr(dgw.Rows(i).Cells(columnNumber).Value)
                End If
                'RB FORMATTING
                If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then '2020/01/01 00:00:00
                    '2020/06/16 19:38:33
                    curcell = curcell.Remove(0, 5)
                    curcell = curcell.Remove(curcell.Length - 9, 9)
                    curcell = curcell.Replace("/", "")
                    '0616
                End If
                'Now we have 0616 in a string which is the date of the current row
                Dim currow As String = ""
                For Each c As DataGridViewCell In dgw.Rows(i).Cells
                    If IsDBNull(c.Value) Then
                        currow += Chr(34) + "" + Chr(34) + ","
                    Else
                        currow += Chr(34) + CStr(c.Value) + Chr(34) + ","
                    End If
                Next

                currow = currow.Remove(currow.Length - 1, 1) 'Remove last comma
                'Now we have the full row to print as well as the date in a string
                Dim FILENAME As String = TextBox2.Text + "\" + curcell + ".csv"

                ' Using fs As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(FILENAME)
                '  AddText(fs, currow + vbCrLf)
                ' End Using

                Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
                Dim w As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs)
                w.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.[End])
                w.Write(currow + vbCrLf)
                w.Close()

                'Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(FILENAME)
                'writer.WriteLine(currow)
                ' End Using


                'My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(FILENAME, currow + vbCrLf, 1)    'Gets used by its own process error some times




                Written += 1
            Next 'Next row
            stop_time = Now
            elapsed_time = stop_time.Subtract(start_time)
            Log("Wrote " + CStr(Written) + " lines in " + elapsed_time.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.00" & " seconds."))

        Catch ex As Exception
            Log(ex.ToString())
        End Try


    End Sub
```

Here's the error:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\TEST2\0416.csv' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at TicketsSQL.frmSplitFiles.btnExec_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\username\source\repos\TicketsSQL\TicketsSQL\frmSplitFiles.vb:line 63
```

I commented out two other ways than the current one that I tried in the code. I tried the following three ways:

```
Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
                Dim w As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs)
                w.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.[End])
                w.Write(currow + vbCrLf)
                w.Close()

Using writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(FILENAME)
writer.WriteLine(currow)
End Using

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(FILENAME, currow + vbCrLf, 1)
```

It seems like no matter what way I try to prevent it using an already open file, or even allowing it to do so... it trips anyway.

Anyone have any work arounds or ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure your `btnExec_Click` handler isn´t called multiple times?

Comment: You're never closing the `FileStream` (declare all these disposable objects with `Using` statements), `File.WriteAllText()` has a different functionality + too many string operations + No idea why you're reading your data from a DataGridView. Is this Control required (at all or at this time)?

Comment: Something like this might possibly be coming from an antivirus program.

Comment: Are you really putting 600,000 rows in a DataGridView?

Comment: @sebjsv If you show us the SQL query, we could probably give even more help to make it run quickly and smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let us know what errors happen

```
    Static start_time As DateTime
    Static stop_time As DateTime
    Dim elapsed_time As TimeSpan
    start_time = Now

    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then columnNumber = CInt(TextBox1.Text) - 1
    Dim dgw = Form1.DataGridView1
    Dim curcell As String = ""
    Dim ToWrite As String = ""
    Dim Written As Integer = 0
    Try

        ProgressBar1.Maximum = dgw.Rows.Count
        For i = 0 To dgw.Rows.Count - 1
            'For each row
            If IsDBNull(dgw.Rows(i).Cells(columnNumber).Value.ToString()) Then
                curcell = "" 'if null replace with a blank value
            Else
                curcell = CStr(dgw.Rows(i).Cells(columnNumber).Value)
            End If
            'RB FORMATTING
            If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then '2020/01/01 00:00:00
                '2020/06/16 19:38:33
                curcell = curcell.Remove(0, 5)
                curcell = curcell.Remove(curcell.Length - 9, 9)
                curcell = curcell.Replace("/", "")
                '0616
            End If
            'Now we have 0616 in a string which is the date of the current row
            Dim currow As String = ""
            For Each c As DataGridViewCell In dgw.Rows(i).Cells
                If IsDBNull(c.Value) Then
                    currow += Chr(34) + "" + Chr(34) + ","
                Else
                    currow += Chr(34) + CStr(c.Value) + Chr(34) + ","
                End If
            Next
            currow = currow.Remove(currow.Length - 1, 1) 'Remove last comma
            '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
            'Now we have the full row to print as well as the date in a string
            Dim FILENAME As String
            FILENAME = IO.Path.Combine(TextBox2.Text, curcell)
            FILENAME = IO.Path.ChangeExtension(FILENAME, ".csv")
            Try
                IO.File.WriteAllText(FILENAME, currow & ControlChars.CrLf)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Stop ' what is the error <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            End Try
            '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            Written += 1
        Next 'Next row
        stop_time = Now
        elapsed_time = stop_time.Subtract(start_time)
        Log("Wrote " + CStr(Written) + " lines in " + elapsed_time.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.00" & " seconds."))

    Catch ex As Exception
        Log(ex.ToString())
    End Try
```